# Issue with getting most recent value in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the latest (most recent) value (0.224469) in this collection :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60112357e06d453f0545f0b4"), "glass" : "7835", "ts" : ISODate("2021-01-27T08:24:55.696Z"), "val" : { "litr" : 0.21405 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60112361e06d453f0545f0b5"), "glass" : "7835", "ts" : ISODate("2021-01-27T08:25:05.694Z"), "val" : { "litr" : 0.215108 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60112393e06d453f0545f0ba"), "glass" : "7835", "ts" : ISODate("2021-01-27T08:25:55.698Z"), "val" : { "litr" : 0.224469 } }
```

I used MAX of "ts" (timestamp of data insertion) field to get the value of field "litr". I tried the following:

```
db.glasss_data.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"glass": "7835"}},
    {"$group": {"_id": null,"MAX(ts)": {"$max": "val"}}}
])
```

the returned result:

`{ "_id" : null, "MAX(ts)" : "val" }`

I expect to get: 0.224469 in the result

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell mongo that you are referring one of the fields in the document.

To say that `$` should be prefixed.

```
"$max": "val"}
```

should be

```
"$max": "$val"}
```

To get the latest data, you can do sort then limit 1

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bSCMyxH6O87)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "glass": "7835"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "ts": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried as you advised: db.glasss_data.aggregate([{"$match": {"glass": "7835"}},{"$group": {"_id": null,"MAX(ts)": {"$max": "$val"}}}]).  The result is the max value not the most recent value.

Comment: Do you need max or recent value based on date?

Comment: most recent value based on the date which is in ts field.

Comment: Check the update, will work in that case.